# Conflicting types for functions in C using header file and makefile

Tags: c, makefile, header-files

I'm using a makefile for C that worked when it just had main.c and data.h but then as soon as I added a function header to data.h and and file for that function which actually defined the function it started erroring at compile time.

I had:

```
/* main.c */
#include "data.h"
int main () { /* this is empty */ }
```

and

```
/* data.h */
char foo(char);
```

and

```
/* foo.c */
#include "data.h"
char foo(char){
    ...
}
```

The error I get is `conflicting types for 'foo'` and `note: previous declaration of 'foo'`.

Other people having this issue had tried to use a function before it was declared or something along those lines but I cant seem to find that coming up in this example.

Comment: What's the actual, full error message?

Comment: And where is the Makefile?

Comment: the makefile is in the same directory as the other files. The full error is `conflicting types for 'foo' data.h:1: note:previous declaration of 'foo' was here`

Comment: Well, I asked about the content of the Makefile. *Where* is the listing of the file in your question? Could you please add it?

Comment: Still not the full error message. The interesting parts are the first and the second filename with line (first filename is missing). Perhaps you name a function the same as in the `#include`d library?

Comment: It would help if you'd post the actual, unedited function prototypes.  For instance, in foo.c it looks like you stripped out the variable name for the argument.  What else did you delete?

Comment: Don't you need variable names for the arguments in the function definition for `foo` in foo.c?

Comment: The function's code is literally empty. The char is called "a".

Answer (score 1):

The error message sounds like the signatures of `foo` in `data.h` is not the same as in `foo.c`

e.g.

```
char foo(char);
```

and

```
char foo(char*);
```

or

```
// missing return type may produce a different/additional warning/error, depending on the compiler
foo(char);
```

Check the specific locations of the conflicting declarations and compare.

Comment: I don't have a data.c

Answer (score -1):

You forgot your include guard in the header file.  It gets included in both C files, so you get the same two function declarations pasted in.  Change your header file like so.

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

char foo(char);

#endif
```

Comment: While generally a good idea, this doesn't explain why the compiler thinks they are *different*.

Comment: Nor is it even relevant. Even without include guards the code posted by the OP, exactly as is, would work.